# Hartl's Tutorial Ch. 7 Exercise 3 No explanation on presence: true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm completely baffled with Exercise 3 in Chapter 7 of Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial. My question is, why do we have to get rid of `presence: true` in order to prevent error duplication. Don't we need that password exists? Or is this one of those things where `has_secure_password` handles this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Validations` for presence of password, confirmation of password (using a "password_confirmation" attribute) are **automatically added**. You can see API of [has_secure_password](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password).

Comment: So I was right in that `has_secure_password` handles that and it's ok to take out the `presence: true` for password?

Comment: yes, no problem if you remove `presence: true` of password, you can try create a user in console without password, and you will see what happens :)